# How to change the lower case to upper case with conditional specific string in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have some text in dataframes, in which I want some specific fruits in upper case. The text is like below
input is

```
one apple
two oranges
three bananas
an apple
```

and 
the output required is

```
one Apple
two Oranges
three Bananas
an Apple
```

The loop I can give condition if array / string / list have any word "one", "two", "three", and "an" **(conditional when these ... any words are in string), after this word, change next followed word first letter lower case to upper case.**

If any hint or help.

5 lines data 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
ID Reference_time Comment
0 0059 one apple box
1 0156 five oranges left
2 1859 an engineer handling issue
3 1555 two persons have eaten, three still hungry
4 2109 an apple carton is still in stock
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Have you not even read the text file and created a dataframe?

Comment: I have imported. its in dataframes already. but it is so big. I cannot place whole. I can only give small 3/4  lines like above

Comment: Well then share a sample of it, say the first 5 rows, with the column names

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you have tried?

Comment: this conditional loop for case change, i could not even built, so asking help

Comment: If it's dataframes you are dealing with, add a pandas tag.

Comment: added as suggested

Comment: Are you trying to capitalize all the fruits? or just the fruits after the  "one", "two", "three", and "an"?

Comment: just any word which is followed by "one", "two", "three", and "an". not all fruits.

Comment: @ML85, Don't know it this would be an issue with the answers given (can't test them right now), but it is worth checking out: Must be aware that those words may be part of other words, for instance `one` may be part of `everyone` or `someone`, same could happen for the other words. So a basic `matching` may lead to wrong results. If you know that the input string could not have this sort of words is fine, but definitely something to keep in mind

Comment: you are right. one problem. it is only detecting one time óne' in a sentence. if this is repeated one apple and one banana, it is reading first óne' only. Also, it is matching it is matching inside word as well, like stone, that st'one' is also considered in first answer / solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably better ways to do this with regex, but this should work using `.str.extract`

only downside will be is that if you have multiple matches in a single string you'll need to handle/edit the regex.

```
repl = ['one','two','three','five','an']
pat = '|'.join(repl)


s = df["comment"].str.extract(rf"({pat})(.*\w.*$)")

s[1] = s[1].str.strip().str.capitalize()
df['comment_new'] = s.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
```

---

```
print(df[['comment_new','comment']])

                                  comment_new  \
0                               one Apple box   
1                           five Oranges left   
2                  an Engineer handling issue   
3  two Persons have eaten, three still hungry   
4           an Apple carton is still in stock   

                                      comment  
0                               one apple box  
1                           five oranges left  
2                  an engineer handling issue  
3  two persons have eaten, three still hungry  
4           an apple carton is still in stock
```

Answer (score 1):

```
keywords = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'an']

df['Comment'] = df['Comment'].apply(lambda x: toUpper(keywords, x))

def toUpper(keywords, sentence):
  word_list = sentence.split()
  for i in range(len(word_list)-1):
    if word_list[i] in keywords:
        word_list[i+1] = word_list[i+1].capitalize()

  return ' '.join(word_list)
```